# How to transport HANA Views from one system to another using Hybris

Tags: hana, sap-commerce-cloud, transport

As stated in the question I want to transport a HANA view from one System (Development) to another (Acceptance).

We use Hybris to transfer views between systems. So I can not use the import-/export dialog of HANA Studio.

Import- / export is explained in [SAP HANA Academy - Transporting Models between HANA systems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMHtThY3cQA)

I want to know how to transport the views via Hybris.

Comment: Hello Thorsten, you probably can do that with datahub. You can find some documentation here : https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/8c48d2d3866910148793f67f2444640c.html. I fear that no one will be able to give you a complete solution for this task. Maybe try something with the datahub and come back later if you have a specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hana Views can be added to a transport via the **transaction `SCTS_HTA`**

Then the transport needs to be released via the transaction `SE10`